# How to change, in the whole document, the color of one single object of a group?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, patterns, automation

I have a pattern made by a group of squares (1st image). Then, I created a pattern copying and pasting it over and over again.

[image]

**My question is**: How to change the color of one single object of the group of squares and change it all over the copies?

See what I want below (I made it by hand editing one by one, I want to make it dynamically):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would delete all but one of the groups. Copy it using dynamic effects (from the appearance panel or Effect -> Distort & Transform -> Transform). Then, changing the one instance will change them all.

To do the transform, first apply a transform in one direction (let's say horizontally). Now, apply a second transform (if you get a dialog box warning you that if you want to edit a transform effect you should click it in the appearance panel, choose to apply a new transform) and make this one transform vertically.

Answer (score 2):

Make an *actual* pattern.

Drag one group to the `Swatches Panel`. Then draw a rectangle and fill it with the new pattern you just made.....

If you want to alter the pattern, double-click it in the Swatches Panel.